# I need an analogue of the function similar_text, but taking into account the substring

Tags: php, similarity

I need to compare two strings for similarity using the `similar_text` function. The problem is that if the difference in length between strings is large, then it gives a bad result, even if the smaller string is an exact substring of the larger one. I wonder if there is such a modification of the function similar_text: take the larger of two strings and extract such a substring from it so that similar_text gives the maximum value. Do not change the first (smaller) line.
For example,

`similar_text ('hello, how are you', 'hello, how you are in Nizhnevartovsk');`

It does not give a good result, but I need to make it work like this:

`similar_text ('hello, how are you', 'hello how you are');`

Is there such a ready-made solution or do I need to write an algorithm for such a modification myself?

Comment: So you're trying to see if string exists within string?

Comment: I try to find similarity between the shorter string and the most appropriate extraction from the other(longer) string. This extraction must be found and then similar_text() applied to it and the first(shorter) string.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do word to word comparison which will only be effective if you decide to take first matches only.Even better if you have an expected starting word and ending word

Comment: The project looks abandoned but you should check it out and attempt to rebuild https://github.com/paulgb/simplediff

Comment: Also this one...pretty old projects but does exactly what you're trying to achieve https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff